# How do I uniformly select the solidity version I want to use in my Ethereum project?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm creating a new Ethereum project, using VScode (with Solidity extension) and hardhat. I want to use Solidity `0.8.1`. I've done the following:

1. Created a new directory for the project
2. Run `npm init -y` to initialise the directory as an npm project
3. Run `npm i -D hardhat` to install hardhat in the local directory (`-D` to save as a dev dependency in the package.json)
4. Run `npx hardhat` and select the option to create the `hardhat.config.js` file
5. Edit the `hardhat.config.js` file to target 0.8.1:

```js
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.1",
};
```

6. Created a contracts folder and created the following file `Token.sol`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

contract doStuff {

}
```

But the Solidity extension in VSCode complains with `Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.3+commit.9bfce1f6.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version`.

I think it's picking up the solc version installed in `node_modules` (`0.7.3`) - this must have been installed as part of `hardhat`.

**How do I line up "everything" in the project so it uses `0.8.1`?**

Presumably you're not forced to use whatever version `hardhat` downloads of `solc` upon installation?

UPDATE:
I ran `npx hardhat compile` which appears to have downloaded the `0.8.1` compiler:

```
✔ Help us improve Hardhat with anonymous crash reports & basic usage data? (Y/n) · true
Downloading compiler 0.8.1
Compiling 1 file with 0.8.1
Compilation finished successfully
```

But the VSCode Solidity extension is still looking at the `solc` version in `node_modules`. How do I point the vscode extension at the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

I had `Enable Local Node Compiler` set to true in my vscode extension config.

Disabling this (through the File -> Preferences GUI) and adding the following to `.vscode/settings.json` sorted the problem:

```json
{
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.8.1+commit.df193b15"
}
```

Comment: I'm also using the remote compiler option that vscode provides but it's quite annoying given that everytime you change the compiler version in your hardhat.config.ts, you also have to remember to the vscode's compiler. I wish there was a way to make vscode use the same compile that `npx hardhat compile` uses...